# Azure - invoke runbook after VM is created

Tags: azure, azure-automation

How do i invoke a `Runbook` after a `VM` is created from the portal? I do not see any way to set the `trigger` and assign a `Runbook` to it?

If this is not possible, how do i achieve this?

Comment: I don't know of any way to trigger like your asking.  Best alternative is to schedule your runbook to periodically look for new VMs.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no direct way to say a runbook should be started after a VM is created, from the portal. This can be done if deploying the VM via an ARM template though, as the [ARM template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/) can declare that a runbook job should be started after the VM has been created.

In terms of a portal-based way, you could create a runbook and have it run on a schedule, polling for new VMs to take some action against, as BenV says. Or you could create a [webhook](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-webhooks/) for the runbook you want to start, and use the [Custom Script Extension](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/24/automating-vm-customization-tasks-using-custom-script-extension/) in your VM to start that webhook. Since the custom script will run once the VM is created, the runbook will be started after the VM is created.